# Joomla, Drupal, DotNetNuke or something else for a sport club?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, joomla, dotnetnuke

I am setting up a web site for a football club and I am wondering which CMS to use. 
I am a developer but I am doing this as a favour to a friend and would rather grab something with modules in it (registration, events, calendar, etc.) already. I need to be able to customise it but I had a look around and Wordpress looks like a blogging tool. I am wondering if anyone has experience with the above or any others and if you could shed some light. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't rule out wordpress yet.. it's fairly powerful and a lot easier to support.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493887/joomla-drupal-or-dotnetnuke , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771467/which-one-is-the-the-best-joomla-dotnetnuke-umbraco-drupal-or-dotcms .

Answer (score 1):

The Major benefit of DotNetNuke is that you will be programming in .Net with all the tools that go with that.  And the db is of course, SQL Server.

So if you are a MS guy, then DNN is a good option.

Day Of DotNetNuke is on in Europe this Friday and we will some slides which demonstrate how to use Telerik and sqlDataSource to build modules in minutes.  These use Telerik grids to give you CRUD functionality in two simple files.  Drop in to Paris if you are free, otherwise, visit the site next week and you can get the slides and some sample code, or else contact me and I will send them to you,

PS.  Not sure why, but you will enjoy working on DNN.

good luck and enjoy.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the current relative merits of the different tools, as it's been a couple of years since I did a comparative evaluation of Drupal, Joomla, WordPress (and 40+ others).

But, I can testify that Drupal would be a good solution for almost any club website.

Out of the box - or with the installation of a commonly used module or three - you could set up:

- Recent News
- Upcoming events (Calendar)
- Blogs (for the club President, Treasurer, other officers, team captains, etc etc)
- Media such as podcasts, videos, etc

Of course, all this is optional. There's heaps of documentation online at http://www.drupal.org covering all this kind of thing.

The key point to take away is this: With Drupal, the challenge your friend will face with the website is *"what to say"* not *"How to make it work*".

Answer (score 0):

It depends how well-versed you are in a particular CMS for example Joomal or Drupal or some other. If you can customize the things easily and be able to modify the CMS as per your needs, you should go with that one as both Joomla and Drupal have big list of extensions to their name. You should have advanced programming concepts especially OOP when it comes to customizing the CMS. The other option is to create everything from scratch on your own. In the end, I would prefer Joomla over Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no experience at all with any CMS, I suggest you Joomla to start with. It is easier to learn and probably enough to manage a football club sites. It is also easier setting a Calendar, Event System and Photo Gallery. Drupal is more flexible, it has great user permission control, but it is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay Portal also has the features you need.

Quick and easy to set up with registration, Calendar ootb. it will be easy for your friend to admin in the future